# Copy normal folder to Team folder using dropboxapi

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

How i can copy Dropbox normal folder to a new TEAM folder?

my original folder:
https://www.dropbox.com/home/Template

im using c# sdk and i tried this

```
using (var dbx = new DropboxTeamClient(tokenMemberFile))
{
  var memListResult = await dbx.Team.MembersListAsync();
  var memId = memListResult.Members.First(x => x.Profile.Email.Equals(adminEmail))
              ?.Profile.TeamMemberId;

  var newFolder = await dbx.Team.TeamFolderCreateAsync(name);
  var relocationArg = new RelocationArg(
                    "/Template"
                    ,"/" + newFolder.Name
                    ,false
                    ,false
                    ,true);
  var copyResult = await dbx.AsAdmin(memId).Files.CopyV2Async(relocationArg);
}
```

error 
`Dropbox.Api.ApiException 1: 'from_lookup/not_found/...'`

Comment: [That `from_lookup/not_found` error](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/T_Dropbox_Api_Files_LookupError_NotFound.htm) indicates that nothing was found at the original path specified in your call, in this case "/Template". Make sure you use the right path(s). You can use [`ListFolderAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm)/[`ListFolderContinueAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderContinueAsync_1.htm) with `path: ""` to check.

Comment: I also recommend reading [the Namespace Guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/namespace-guide) for information on how to navigate Dropbox folders in the API.